# Access VBA find the last occurrent of a string?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Access VBA has Instr to return the position of the first occurrence of a string in another string.

```
Instr ( [start], string_being_searched, string2, [compare] )
```

Is there any method to return the position of the last occurrence of a string in another string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `InstrRev` instead - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251545.aspx)

Note the different syntax to `InStr`:

`InstrRev(stringcheck, stringmatch[, start[, compare]])`

Comment: Good answer!  This is not specific to MS Access.  It will work anywhere VBA is used.

Answer (score 4):

Check this link, example code from MS

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a(v=vs.90).aspx

```
Dim TestString As String = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" 
Dim TestNumber As Integer 
' Returns 32.
TestNumber = InStrRev(TestString, "the")
' Returns 1.
TestNumber = InStrRev(TestString, "the", 16)
```